# Expression of type List[Any] doesn't comform to expected type List[T]

Tags: scala

IntelliJ complains the "Expression of type List[Any] doesn't  conform to expected type List[T]" on the line **first :: pack(rest)**.

```
  val data = List("a", "a", "a", "b", "c", "c", "a")

  def pack[T](xs: List[T]): List[T] = xs match {
    case Nil => Nil
    case x :: xs1 =>
      val (first, rest) = xs span (y => y == x)
      first :: pack(rest)
  }
  pack(data)
```

When pattern match found the original list is a not Nil, it will have least one member. That is x :: xs1. When span is applied on the original list with the condition y => y == x, it should return a List. In this example, for the first found character 'a', it should return List(a,a,a) which then match the first. 
I couldn't figure out why Scala complained.

The objective is to have a list

```
List(List(a, a, a), List(b), List(c, c), List(a))
```

P.S. 
My return type is wrong it should be List[List[T]]. thanks for all your help.

Comment: `first` and `rest` both have type `List[T]`. To concatenate two lists, use `++`, not `::`.

Comment: `x :: pack(xs.dropWhile(_ == x))` ?

Comment: replace `case Nil => Nil` by `List[T]()` and `first :: pack(rest)` by `x :: pack(rest)`

Comment: Edited my answer for your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Now that you have clarified the requirement. You want to have `List(List(a, a, a), List(b), List(c, c), List(a))` as output for an input `List("a", "a", "a", "b", "c", "c", "a")`.

The thing is that `Nil` by itself is of type `scala.collection.immutable.Nil.type` so the overall return type of your `pack` function is being interpreted as `List[Any]`.

So, replace `case Nil => Nil` by `List[T]()` and `first :: pack(rest)` by `x :: pack(rest)`.

Also,`y => y == x` is not safe to compare objects, replace this by `y => y.equals(x)`.

```
val data = List("a", "a", "a", "b", "c", "c", "a")

def pack[T](xs: List[T]): List[List[T]] = xs match {
  case Nil => List.empty[List[T]]
  case x :: xs1 => {
    val (first, rest) = xs.span(t => t.equals(x))
    first :: pack(rest)
  }
}

pack(data)
```

Comment: I don't think you need to return List.empty[List[T]] for Nil. And y => y == x is perfectly fine too

Comment: No... `y == x` actually acts differently than it should in case of some special cases such as `Double.NaN == Double.Nan`. And yes that `Nil` will not cause much problem here but it can really confuse the type inference in complex cases. Remember being explicitly never hurts and it also make your code more readable.

Answer (score 0):

```
val data = List("a", "a", "a", "b", "c", "c", "a")

def pack[T](xs: List[T]): List[List[T]] = {
  def helper(map: Map[T, Int])(xs: List[T]): Map[T, Int] = xs match {
    case Nil => map
    case x :: xs =>
      if (map contains x) {
        helper(map + (x -> (map(x) + 1)))(xs)
      } else {
        helper(map +  (x -> 1))(xs)
      }
  }
  helper(Map.empty[T, Int])(xs).map { case (x, count) => List.fill(count)(x) }.toList
}

println(pack(data))

scala> println(pack(data))
List(List(a, a, a, a), List(b), List(c, c))
```

Comment: @jwvh what does `pack` do

Comment: My point exactly! As it is, it doesn't **do** anything. I _think_ what the OP had in mind is to remove adjacent duplicates.  If that's the case then Victor Moroz's suggestion is the way to go.

Comment: OK, that's progress.  I don't think that's what the OP wants, but I've been wrong before.  Hopefully @johnsam will eventually step up and explain what the code is _supposed_ to do.

Comment: Thanks I found my problem which is in your answer that my return type is wrong.